# Jasmine with Coffeescript Unexpected string Syntax error

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, jasmine, jasmine-node

I'm trying Jasmine in Coffeescript but when i call `jasmine` in the terminal, I get this error:

```
/home/luca/tries/sourcemaps-demo/spec/mainSpec.coffee:1
nction (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { describe 'A suite',
                                                                ^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected string
  at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
  at require (module.js:380:17)
  at /home/luca/.nvm/v0.10.35/lib/node_modules/jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:63:5
at Array.forEach (native)
at Jasmine.loadSpecs (/home/luca/.nvm/v0.10.35/lib/node_modules/jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:62:18)
at Jasmine.execute (/home/luca/.nvm/v0.10.35/lib/node_modules/jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:145:8)
```

This is my spec/support/jasmine.json:

```
{
   "spec_dir": "spec",
   "spec_files": [
     "**/*[sS]pec.coffee"
   ],
   "helpers": [
     "helpers/**/*.coffee"
   ]
}
```

And this is my spec/mainSpec.coffee:

```
describe 'A suite', ->
  it 'should return true', ->
    expect(true).toBe true
```

I'm missing something?

Comment: I looks like you have not compiled the coffeescript code.

Comment: @Bergi Yep, you are right, I've not compiled it intentionally, I thought Jasmine would understand it automatically... I really have to pre-compile my mainSpec.coffee to mainSpec.js?

Answer (score 1):

`jasmine` does not support `coffee-script`. If You want to write tests in `coffee-script`, use `jasmine-node`

```
$npm install -g jasmine-node
$jasmine-node --coffee spec/
.

Finished in 0.01 seconds
1 test, 1 assertion, 0 failures, 0 skipped
```

Comment: It help me. Great. But I am surprise that Jasmine doesn't compile coffeescritps